# Is there any sort of HTML-to-string functionality in AMPScript?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I'm pulling an RSS feed into my landing page using code [similar to this:](https://help.exacttarget.com/sv/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/how_to_include_an_rss_feed_in_an_email_message_using_ampscript/)

So, I've got all that code sitting inside a single variable right now.  When I print out that single  variable on a landing page, I get nicely-formatted HTML, and the HTML displays very nicely.

But, I really want the HTML code to be converted into a string so that the browser won't try to interpret and display the formatted HTML.  I'd like to just print a big block of HTML code inside my landing page.

Isn't there some sort of functionality where I can turn a chunk of HTML into a string?

How would you accomplish this?  Is it even possible to do this with AMPScript?

Edit: I can't delete this question, but I didn't explain the problem clearly enough or specifically enough to allows others to offer useful advice.  I'll need to think of a better way to state the question and repost.

Comment: I think that I need to repost and rephrase the question.

Answer (score 2):

Wrapping the @html variable in `<xmp>` worked for me:

```
<xmp>%%=v(@html)=%%</xmp>
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1756164/how-to-print-code-on-html

Answer (score 1):

How about just parsing the HTML and replacing the "<" and ">" characters with HTML entities -- before you display it on the page?

```
%%[

var @html
set @html = "<table><tr><td>whee!</td></tr></table>"
set @html = replace(replace(@html,">","&gt;"),"<","&lt;")

]%%

<pre>%%=v(@html)=%%</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

Trying wrapping that string in TreatAsContent()

http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/content_ampscript_functions/#TreatAsContent

Comment: TreatAsContent() just forces the AMPScript to be evaluated.